# Как сделать кулдаун для слеш команды?

Tags: python, discord.py

Вот у меня есть кусок кода:

```
@bot.slash_command(description='Работа')
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test")
```

Как сделать ответ? Например. Не удалось использовать команду, попробуйте через 60 секунд!
(или сколько там осталось)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
@bot.slash_command(description='Работа')
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType)
async def test(ctx):
    try:
        await ctx.send("test")
    except commands.CommandOnCooldown as e:
        remaining_time = round(e.retry_after)
        await ctx.send(f"Не удалось использовать команду, попробуйте через {remaining_time} секунд(ы)!")
```